# Why it is impossible to define a this-constructor in the trait?

Tags: scala

I read in Martin Odersky's book that trait extends a superclass AnyRef. So it's like a class for me. I know I cannot use default constructor in the trait which I usually use in the class

```
class B(s: String)
```

At the same time, I can see that it's impossible to do something like this

```
trait A {
  def this(s: String) {
    super()  
  }
}
```

Compiler says:

```
Error:(14, 7) 'this' expected but 'super' found.
  super()
  ^
```

Why is that so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straight from the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#traits):

> A trait is a class that is meant to be added to some other class as a mixin. Unlike normal classes, **traits cannot have constructor parameters**. Furthermore, no constructor arguments are passed to the superclass of the trait. This is not necessary as traits are initialized after the superclass is initialized.

What it comes down to is:

1. traits boil down to java interfaces, which have no parameters, which is nice for java-interop.
2. While it may be theoretically possible to allow traits to have
   constructor parameters, it makes the language more complex than it
   needs to be. There is almost certainly a way to accomplish the same functionality, without the need for trait constructor parameters.

Comment: Trait parameters are coming to the language. Then they can drop early definitions.